# How do I Render a view with Ajax in Laravel 9

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel

I want to render a view without refreshing my page, so I use Ajax and render the view. It look likes my $scores won't work, should it be an array or not? I've read something about it should be json data?

Controller:

```
$scores = DB::table('scores')->select('teamname', 'score')->get();
$table_view = view('score_table.blade.php', ['scores'=>$scores])->render();
return response()->json(['succes' => true, 'table_view' => $table_view]);
```

View score_table.blade.php

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Teamname </th>
        <th> Score </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($scores as $score)
        <tr>
            <td> {{ $score->teamname }} </td>
            <td> {{ $score->score }} </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Ajax function

```
 success:function(data){
            
            $('#scoreresult').html(data.table_view);

         }
```

I was pretty sure that it would work, but it didn't :(. Who can help me with a solution? Many thanks!

Comment: "It look likes my $scores won't work" - what does that mean? Did you check what `$table_view` contains? Or what the controller returns? Maybe this is not an AJAX problem on its own?

Comment: For rendering view without refreshing page You can also use livewire - full-stack framework for Laravel. For me it's excellent. https://laravel-livewire.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is fine but few changes required.

You don't have to pass full name of blade file and can use compact.

Controller:

```
$scores = DB::table('scores')->select('teamname', 'score')->get();
$table_view = view('score_table', compact('scores'))->render();
return response()->json(['succes' => true, 'table_view' => $table_view]);
```

Also confirm if you are sending content type as json in the ajax request.

```
dataType: "json",
success:function(data){
      $('#scoreresult').html(data.table_view);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same requirement but got some issues when I tried doing the following:

```
$view =   view('pages.portals.admin.partials.view-model')->with("model",$thisModel)
 ->render();
  return response()->json(['view'=>$view]);
```

the problem I got was the page refreshing itself every Ajax request using Axios library as follows:

```
axios.get(path).then(function(res) {
                if (res.data.view) {
                    $(res.data.view).appendTo("body");
                    //show the modal dialog
                    $('#modelView').modal({
                            centered: false,
                            closable: false,
                            onHidden:function(){
                                $(this).remove();
                            }
                        })
                        .modal('show');
                }

            });
```

I solved the problem by attaching `application/json`  on my request **headers** as follows:

```
 axios.get(path,{
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },

            }).then(function(res) {

                if (res.data.view) {
                    $(res.data.view).appendTo("body");
                    //show the modal dialog
                    $('#modelView').modal({
                            centered: false,
                            closable: false,
                            onHidden:function(){
                                $(this).remove();
                            }
                        })
                        .modal('show');
                }

            });
```

Comment: Why not try to use `dataType: json`, as given in the accepted answer? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it